# What is the cheapest way for an off-chain oracle to demonstrate "proof of life" to a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Suppose you have a smart contract which relies on an off-chain [oracle](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/07/22/ethereum-and-oracles/) in order to function effectively. In fact, suppose that this oracle is so important to your contract, that you want to disable your contract if the oracle goes offline.

Clearly, the contract cannot directly check whether the oracle is online; it must rely on more indirect means. In your opinion, what is the cheapest way (in terms of Ether spent) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach I can think of is to have the oracle "check in" with the contract periodically, like so:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract MyContract {
    address public oracle;
    uint public lastAliveTime;

    modifier throwUnless(bool condition) {
        if (!condition) { throw; }
        _;
    }

    function MyContract() {
        oracle = msg.sender;
        showProofOfLife();
    }

    function showProofOfLife() throwUnless(msg.sender == oracle) {
        lastAliveTime = now;
    }

    function doSomethingUseful() throwUnless((now - lastAliveTime) < 15 minutes) {
        // Do something useful...
    }
}
```

According to the online solidity compiler, the `showProofOfLife` function has a transaction cost of 26543 gas. At the current average gas price (0.000000024289033632 ether/gas) that works out to about **0.00064470381 ether**/transaction.

That may not seem like much, but if you call that function every 15 minutes for an entire year it'll cost you over 22 ether!

Answer (score 1):

What do you need this oracle for?

Conventionally an oracle needs to be providing some kind of information to the blockchain that will be read by code triggered by transactions. In that case, store the time the information was published and check that it's new enough in the transactions that read it.

If there's some kind of process that you don't want to kick off until you're sure that the oracle is online then Mugu The Mangler's solution might be the best you can do, but you can't solve the problem perfectly, because it may go offline between sending the last scheduled ping and kicking off whatever the process is.

One process that would avoid the need to keep on sending ping transactions would be set things up so that you can contact the oracle out-of-band (say by pinging an HTTP URL) then send a transaction to a contract (with a bond or reputation or some other way of avoiding deliberate false alarms) claiming that the oracle is offline, then have the oracle watch for that transaction and, if it sees it, send its own transaction to say "No, I'm still here", or "I was offline but now I'm back up."

Comment: I think perhaps I misused the term "oracle". In this case, I was imagining that the oracle was an internet-connected bot, and that the oracle would watch events posted by the contract and use these events to trigger some behavior. For example, perhaps the oracle would make a post on StackExchange whenever someone called the contract's `doSomethingUseful()` function.

Comment: I don't think.you misused it, it's just very vague, people are using it to mean all kinds of things.